# Encrypted - Password Protect VBS Script

Tags: encryption, vbscript, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I would like to password protect my vbs script so you have to enter a password to be able to run it.

But, not as a popup box but as a command line argument.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To encode vb script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606227/to-encode-vb-script)

Comment: Closest you are going to get I'm afraid *(disclaimer: it isn’t encryption)*. Your only other option would be some third party software that runs from the command line and decrypts / encrypts the file then calls it via `cscript.exe` afterwards. There is no “in-built” facility in VBScript though.